# How do I get eclipse to automatically add a semicolon?

Tags: java, eclipse

Here is the situation. I have the following Java code:

```
String a;
a.
```

Right after I press the "." I get the popup menu with the String methods. I choose one, fill in the arguments, but then I have to press the right-arrow key to get past the ) so I can type in the ;

In Emacs I used a macro (meta-Enter I think) which, when pressed, would add a semicolon to the end of the current line and then place me in the next line, at the proper indentation. Is there such a macro in eclipse?

Comment: I assume you mean you type the *right-arrow* key to get past the `)` so you can type a `;`. You can also hit `enter` while in template mode to skip to the end of a just-inserted method. So if you're happy with the defaults that come with a content proposal, you can just hit enter twice, to insert it and then skip to the end of the line.

Comment: Ahh, yes, thanks. It is faster to type "enter ; enter" than the "right-arrow ; enter" I was using. Still "enter meta-enter" would be even faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of Eclipse plugins that can help you with that:

- Jcolon: Intelligent Semicolon Inserter For Eclipse 4 http://mystilleef.github.io/eclipse4-jcolon/
- Smart Semicolon https://code.google.com/p/smartsemicolon/

Answer (score 18):

This inserts the semicolon at the end of the line, but you still have to type it :

> Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing > check "semicolons"

Still, better than nothing.

Comment: I had not seen that. Thanks. But, after checking that box I repeated the steps in the question and no semicolons are added.

Comment: When you type a semicolon, this option puts it at the end of the line, no more no less. I know it doesn't solve the issue you're facing, but it's an improvement (2 keys to press instead of 3), so I mentioned it.

Answer (score 6):

See this [link](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/02/22/place-a-semicolon-at-the-end-of-a-java-statement-in-eclipse/).

"The preference is disabled by default, so you have to enable it. Go to **Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing.** Then enable Semicolons under the section Automatically insert at correct position.

Now when you press semicolon from anywhere in a statement, Eclipse adds a semicolon to the end of the line and places the cursor right after the semicolon so you can start editing the next line."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which OS you are using, but don't forget that Eclipse, like the rest of the applications on your system, can be manipulated using external macro programs using simple UI commands.

I use a Mac and I use a program called Keyboard Maestro. What you asked took me about a minute to perform. Simply go to the end of the line, type ";" and press return to go to the next line (Eclipse takes care or indenting). I'm sure you can find similar tools for your OS of choice.